# React: - Parent Component referencing State of Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React and am trying to figure out the best way to build form components that support flexible multi-lingual information.

To handle translation on the server-side, String properties have been replaced by a Translation object property, which allows a flexible way to support as many translations of the field content as are needed/available. When the data comes from the server as JSON, it follows the same object design and takes a nested format (simplified for example purposes):

```
{"book": {
    "id": 1,
    "isbn": "978-1853260414",
    "name": {
        "translation": {
            "id": 100,
            "usage": "Book name",
            "translationContents":
            [
                {"id": 2000, "language": "EN", "content": "The Great Gatsby", "status":10},
                {"id": 2001, "language": "ES", "content": "El gran Gatsby", "status":20},
                {"id": 2002, "language": "FR", "content": "Gatsby le magnifique", "status":10}
            ]
        }
    },
    "synopsis": {
        "translation": {
            "id": 101,
            "usage": "Book synopsis",
            "translationContents":
            [
                {"id": 2003, "language": "EN", "content": "A consummate summary of the roaring twenties", "status":10},
                {"id": 2004, "language": "ES", "content": "Un resumen consumado de los locos años veinte", "status":10},
                {"id": 2005, "language": "FR", "content": "Un résumé parfait des années folles", "status":30}
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

In React, I need to create a Component that allows the user to edit all the data in a single form i.e.

- ISBN (isbn)
- Name Usage (name.translation.usage)
- Name Content EN (name.translation.translationContents[0].content)
- Name Status EN (name.translation.translationContents[0].status)
- Name Content ES (name.translation.translationContents[1].content)
- Name Status ES (name.translation.translationContents[1].status)
- Name Content FR (name.translation.translationContents[2].content)
- Name Status FR (name.translation.translationContents[2].status)
- Synopsis Usage (synposis.translation.usage)
- Synopsis Content EN (synposis.translation.translationContents[0].content)
- Synopsis Status EN (synposis.translation.translationContents[0].status)
- Synopsis Content ES (synposis.translation.translationContents[1].content)
- Synopsis Status ES (synposis.translation.translationContents[1].status)
- Synopsis Content FR (synposis.translation.translationContents[2].content)
- Synopsis Status FR (synposis.translation.translationContents[2].status)

In theory, I thought I could follow the same structure as JSON for my JavaScript objects.

Then using React, create reusable Translation and TranslationContent Components that build the form input fields:

```
<Book>
   <TextField> // ISBN
   <Translation> // Name
      <TranslationContent /> // EN
      <TranslationContent /> // ES
      <TranslationContent /> // FR
   </Translation>
   <Translation> // Synposis
      <TranslationContent /> // EN
      <TranslationContent /> // ES
      <TranslationContent /> // FR
   </Translation>
</Book>
```

This is possible, but I hit a stumbling block with React State. I need Book to keep a reference to the property values of its Translation children (and Translation to keep a reference the property values of its TranslationContent children) so Book can eventually post all of the updated properties back to the server.

**Object Reference via Props**

I tried passing a JavaScript object from Book to Translation via Props:

`<Translation data={this.nameTranslationData}  />`

And in Translation constructor:

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = props.data;
}
```

My expectation was, when the child Translation object updates its State properties, this is then automatically updated on the parent Book because they're pointing to the same JavaScript object. However, this doesn't happen and it appears as though Translation State creates a copy of the props.data object and so changes to Translation State properties, stay within the Translation scope and aren't reflected in the Book parent property this.nameTranslationData.

**Callback via Props**

The only way I have found so far is creating a callback method for each field in Book e.g.

```
nameTranslationStateCallBack=(updatedTranslationState)=>{this.nameTranslationData=translationState;};
```

...and passing it to the Translation child via Props:

```
<Translation data={this.nametranslationData} sendStateToParentCallback={this.nameTranslationStateCallBack} />
```

..and each time I detect a change in the Translation child Component form field, it sends a copy of its State back to the parent:

```
this.props.sendStateToParentCallback(this.state);
```

The same functionality then also has to exist between Translation and its TranslationContent child Components.

However, this seems quite messy repetitive code and, on larger forms with lots of translation fields, it's creating a lot of callback methods, which I'm worried could also be inefficient cascading updates to the parent in this way. That's why it would be great if the child Component's state was the same object as the parent's reference.

As I'm new to React, it's possible I am approaching this problem completely the wrong way or missing an obvious solution. I would be grateful for any advice on how to best structure this, as once I adopt an approach, it will be used throughout the application.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try using a redux store to push and use the data across components?

Comment: You can create one static callback and pass it to all fields

Comment: @vvk24 - I haven't used Redux before, but will check it out. Thank you

Comment: @Pablo - thanks for your reply. Would you be able to expand at all as I did not follow how I would implement that? Many thanks